# Visual Editor is giving me 500 Errors

Tags: mediawiki, mediawiki-extensions, visual-editor

**Error contacting the Parsoid/RESTBase server: (curl error: 60) SSL peer certificate or SSH remote key was not OK**

That is the error I receive when I set HTTPS in $wgServer.
and

**Error contacting the Parsoid/RESTBase server (HTTP 500)**

That is the error I receive when I put HTTP in $wgServer.

It is not a private wiki and is hosted on a domain with a successful SSL Certificate. What do I do to fix this?

Comment: I've also been told that you shouldn't need to install anything extra for this to work.

Comment: You need to check the server's error log for more details. Please add them to the question, along with more details about how to reproduce the error

Comment: Okay, so I diagnosed it and it only gives me an error on the Main Page,